# AngularJS, Modal, "Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, undefined, splice

I am trying to make the Bootstrap Modal to work as an alertbox for my setup. When I run the code in JSFiddle and try to delete a note it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined". When I run the same code in Visual Studios is doesn´t give me the error but it deletes the wrong note. It deletes the first note created.
Please [take a look at the fiddle that I created](http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1006/).

```js
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.sortable','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

    var i;
    $scope.itemsList = {
        items1: [],
        items2: []
    };

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1) {
        $scope.itemsList.items1.push({ 'Id': i, 'Label': 'Item ' + i });
    }
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        containment: '#sortable-container',
        accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {
            return sourceItemHandleScope.itemScope.sortableScope.$id === destSortableScope.$id;
        }
    };

    $scope.addNote = function() {
    $scope.itemsList.items1.push({"Id" :  $scope.itemsList.items1.length, "Label": "Item " +     $scope.itemsList.items1.length})
    }

    $scope.alert = function () {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'openAlertBox.html',
            scope: $scope,
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.ok = function (index) {
                    $scope.itemsList.items.splice(index, 1)
                    $scope.$dismiss();
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $scope.$dismiss()
                }
            }
        })
    }

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/a5hik/ng-sortable/master/dist/ng-sortable.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="sortable-container">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="input-append">
                <form>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="addNote()">
                        Add Note
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sortable-row" as-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="itemsList.items1">
            <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList.items1" class="simpel-fighter-input" as-sortable-item>
                <input class="category-form textboxid" type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.Label" placeholder="Deltager1">
                <div as-sortable-item-handle class="touch-mover">MOVE ME</div>
                <a ng-click="alert()" href><div class="touch-mover">DELETE</div></a>
                <input class="category-form textboxid" style="float:right" type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.Label2" placeholder="Deltager2">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="openAlertBox.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">You are about to delete</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>du you really want to delete?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the index from initial html :

```
<a ng-click="alert($index)" href><div class="touch-mover">DELETE</div></a>
```

And in $scope.alert function, instead of taking index as parameter to 'ok' function, take index as parameter to alert function and use it in 'ok' function.

```
$scope.alert = function (index) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked with a combination from Alex' comment.

Comment: Working Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1024/

Answer (score 1):

You `index` args in $scope.ok method is undefined. You need pass index of item in params.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you do not have "items" array :) its called "items1" so you need just to change this

```
$scope.itemsList.items1.splice(index, 1)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I did that and now it works on the delete. But it deletes the wrong note. It deletes the top note no matter which one I select.

Comment: With the comment from Yeswanth i worked with yours as. Thank you Alex!